# Interpolating a cardinal curve in C#

Tags: c#, math, interpolation, gdi+, curve

I need to manually interpolate a cardinal curve/spline - the type of curve created by System.Drawing's DrawCurve method. I've found a wonderful C example of DeCastelJau's Algorithm to do this with beziers. Sadly, all the examples I find for this type of curve are pure mathematical notation, which may as well be cuneiform to me.

Can anyone possibly point me to an example of interpolating (and this having all the points crossed by) this kind of curve, demonstrated in a programming language, which is what I know how to read?

Edit:

I was asked for an example of the pure math approach to this which is alien to me. This is the most verbose one I could find, which I imagine would give you the most to work with: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904569900409

Comment: Please include the reference link so we understand what you have been looking at.

Comment: @Aldert - Do you mean an example of the type of curve, or of the mathematical notation I cannot make sense of?

Comment: The math you cannot make sense of

Comment: _all the points crossed by_ Meaning what? Infinite, all x, all y, or just many? (For the latter create and flatten a graphicspath.)

Comment: @TaW - Well, DeCastelJau always gives you 1,000 coordinate points. I'd be satisfied with that, since then they'd both yield a predictable scope. I looked into trying to get a graphicspath to dump its points, but evidently modern dotnet won't do it?

Comment: The points (and control points) are in the pathPoints array. But since we are talking bezier they are not all on the actual curve. But you can `flatten` the path to line segements which all should be on the 'curve'..

Comment: @TaW - You're right. I stand corrected, they've just changed how you get to it a bit since the last time I tried to interrogate a graphicspath on that level. For some reason, when I looked into that last night, Google didn't give me anything on it. A minute ago I found docs on it - on the Russian version of the MSDN page. Thank god for Chrome's translator ...

Comment: If you want to work with manually implementing geometry, you're going to have to do at least _some_ maths, but for just drawing them it doesn't go beyond early high school maths. Have a look at the first few sections of https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo, which should at least get you from section 1 to section 8 (ignoring 6) without losing you. Accept that some of the notation is "for mathematicians" and is there to write out "a lot of work with not a lot of symbols" and just focus on the textual explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft cardinal spline is kind of cubic [Hermite spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Cardinal_spline).

Hermite spline is described by end points and tangent vectors in these points `P0, P1, m0, m1`.

For interpolation of point set cardinal splines give continuity of the first order (values and tangents are synchronized for neighbor spline pieces). To achieve this, one need to set tangents at `k`-th point

```
 m(k) = (1-c) * (P(k+1) - P(k-1)) / (t(k+1)-t(k-1))
```

where c is tension, `P(k)`  is `k`-th point of data set, and `t(k)` is some parameter for normalization. Sometimes indexes are used (c.f. more general Kochanek-Bartels splines use denominator 2 as index difference), sometimes cumulative distance between points - I suspect MS might use this method and so on.

So you can calculate tangents `m(k)` in every point of dataset (excluding starting and ending ones - here just apply tangent based on single neighbor) and build splines in Hermite form (basis).

But there is rather simple de Casteljau method for Bezier curves - so we can express the same curves in Bezier form (change basis to Bernstein polynomials).  Cited wiki page shows simple way: starting and ending points stay the same, and control points of Bezier are

```
p0 (Bezier) = p0 (Hermite)
p3 (Bezier) = p1 (Hermite)
p1(Bezier) = p0(Hermite) + m0/3
p2(Bezier) = p1(Hermite) - m1/3
```

Comment: This actually clears a lot of things up. Thank you very much.